# Ubuntu 20.04 problems shown by fsck

Tags: fsck

[image: disk partitions]

I carried out `sudo fsck.ext4 -fn /dev/sda5` and got the following result.

```
rajiv@rajiv-Inspiron-7348:~$ sudo fsck.ext4 -fn /dev/sda5
[sudo] password for rajiv: 

e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Warning!  /dev/sda5 is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 5506502 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? no

Inode 5507767 extent tree (at level 1) could be narrower.  Optimize? no

Inode 5508754 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Optimize? no

Inode 5510330 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Optimize? no

Inode 5517112 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Optimize? no

Deleted inode 5517211 has zero dtime.  Fix? no

Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix? no

Inode 5518822 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 5529604 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Optimize? no

Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Entry 'broadcast-listeners.json' in /home/rajiv/.mozilla/firefox/7wrek8um.default (5505153) has deleted/unused inode 5532012.  Clear? no

Entry 'timestamps' in /var/lib/NetworkManager (23200024) has deleted/unused inode 23201619.  Clear? no

Entry 'CE28D9C4414774BCF9756F3F9B803AFFD8609479' in /home/rajiv/.cache/mozilla/firefox/7wrek8um.default/cache2/entries (5505166) has deleted/unused inode 5532035.  Clear? no

Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Unattached zero-length inode 5526783.  Clear? no

Unattached inode 5526783
Connect to /lost+found? no

Unattached inode 5528303
Connect to /lost+found? no

Unattached zero-length inode 23207250.  Clear? no

Unattached inode 23207250
Connect to /lost+found? no

Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -22127947 -(22132180--22132181) +22217427 +(22221742--22221746) +(22353823--22353841) +92916013 -92916014 -(92916345--92916355) +(92917070--92917075) -(92917114--92917119)
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong for group #675 (3232, counted=3229).
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong for group #678 (7821, counted=7827).
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong for group #682 (9244, counted=9263).
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong for group #2374 (2863, counted=3617).
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong for group #2378 (0, counted=2048).
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong for group #2379 (10126, counted=12050).
Fix? no

Free blocks count wrong (84360806, counted=82966438).
Fix? no

Inode bitmap differences:  -5517211 -5518822 -5528027 +5531296 +5531298 -5532012 -5532035 -5532255 -23201619 +23207250
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong for group #674 (1, counted=0).
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong for group #675 (578, counted=577).
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong for group #691 (4127, counted=4128).
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong (36381309, counted=36382521).
Fix? no

Inode bitmap differences: Group 674 inode bitmap does not match checksum.
IGNORED.
Group 675 inode bitmap does not match checksum.
IGNORED.
Group 691 inode bitmap does not match checksum.
IGNORED.
Group 2832 inode bitmap does not match checksum.
IGNORED.
Block bitmap differences: Group 675 block bitmap does not match checksum.
IGNORED.
Group 678 block bitmap does not match checksum.
IGNORED.
Group 682 block bitmap does not match checksum.
IGNORED.
Group 2374 block bitmap does not match checksum.
IGNORED.
Group 2378 block bitmap does not match checksum.
IGNORED.
Group 2379 block bitmap does not match checksum.
IGNORED.
Group 2835 block bitmap does not match checksum.
IGNORED.

/dev/sda5: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

/dev/sda5: 2022787/38404096 files (0.8% non-contiguous), 69238938/153599744 blocks
```

I can see there are multiple problems with my disk structure. How do I set this right?

Comment: Why are you trying to check a disk while it is in use/mounted? Repeat with disk not mounted, and replace output by the new output - use "edit" to update your question.

Comment: If you try to fix a mounted disk, it will destroy all data on it,

Comment: Edit your question and show me screenshots of the `Disks` app **SMART Data** (scrollable) window. I want to look at the condition of your hard disk.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

To check/repair your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Note: If you have Windows, and you've installed any drivers that allow you to read/write to linux ext2/3/4 partitions, remove it asap, as these drivers corrupt linux partitions.

Note: Edit your question and show me screenshots of the `Disks` app **SMART Data** (scrollable) window. I want to look at the condition of your hard disk.